# mod_rewrite in .htaccess to replace .aspx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have converted a website from ASP to php...and the urls no longer require an extension.  I want to strip off ".aspx" from the end of my incoming strings (from search engines for example) and then 302 redirect them to the correct page without that extension so that the rest of my mod_rewrite rules can then take over.  How would I do this?

```
OLD URL:  www.mysite.com/test/page/here.aspx
NEW URL:  www.mysite.com/test/page/here/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this rule into your `.htaccess` file in root folder (before catch-all rewrite rule, if you have such):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `http://www.example.com/test/page/here.aspx` to `http://www.example.com/test/page/here/`.

Please note, it is better (at least from SEO/browser point of view) to have 301 redirect code (Permanent Redirect) instead of 302 (Found/Temporal Redirect). Unless you may consider changing website back to aspx.

Comment: Perfect.  Works like a charm.  Thanks also for correcting my redirect code number...I never can keep all the 300's straight.